# What to use to signal "select" internally?

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, embedded-linux

I am designing a robot that runs on Linux, I want to have a telemetry only interface from the robot that runs on TCP/IP mostly for my own education about TCP but also for guaranteed packet ordering and the checksum. My current design is to have three threads:

1. Thread that listens for connections and adds new connections to `the list`
2. Thread that collects the telemetry from the other parts of the system and sends it to each connection in `the list`
3. Thread that `select`'s on `the list` and removes any clients that disconnect from the list

I'd like thread `1` to be able to signal thread `3` "Hey buddy, new connection, update your list", the obvious answer to me is create some additional file/pipe that can be added to `3`'s `select` list and if the additional file is the one signaled update the list. I think a file or a pipe is bit of overkill for signaling though,I should think a binary semaphore would do the trick, but I don't know how to `select` on a binary semaphore.

I guess my question is: what thinks can you turn into a file descriptor so you can select on them?

My secondary question is: I am a "older school" Linux/C developer trying to come up to speed on more modern techniques, specifically modern c++, is there a more "modern c++" way to do this?

Comment: I think a pipe or a socket is what you want to use for signaling to select().

Comment: Linux has `eventfd()` for that. And your thread 2 and 3 should be one thread. Thread 1 can probably be merged into it too.

Comment: Modern C++ would use asio or the like.

Comment: You should combine threads 1 and 3. No reason for them to be separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`eventfd(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) is a handy Linux-specific API that is meant for this sort of notification. It creates a file descriptor that can be used to signal events by writing to it.

Example using it (And `poll()`, which is generally preferable to `select()`):

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/eventfd.h>

void messenger(int efd) {
  while (1) {
    std::uint64_t i = 1;
    if (write(efd, &i, sizeof i) != sizeof i) {
      std::perror("write");
      std::exit(1);
    }
    sleep(1);
  }
}

int main() {
  int efd = eventfd(0, 0);
  if (efd < 0) {
    std::perror("eventfd");
    return 1;
  }
  std::thread messenger_thread{messenger, efd};
  struct pollfd waiter[1];

  waiter[0].fd = efd;
  waiter[0].events = POLLIN;
  
  while (poll(waiter, 1, -1) >= 0) {
    if (waiter[0].revents & POLLIN) {
      std::uint64_t i;
      if (read(efd, &i, sizeof i) != sizeof i) {
        std::perror("read");
        return 1;
      }
      std::puts("Signaled by messenger.");
    }
  }
}
```

---

As noted in my earlier comment, though, I think this is the wrong architecture - you really shouldn't have another thread just to detect closed connections, as those are generally signaled via a failed read or write on the socket - it's best done in the same thread that's sending data to them. And it's easy to have a non-blocking listening socket that you also poll for and `accept()` when readable - basically, it's easier to do everything in one thread instead of trying to split it up. *Collecting* the data from your robot telemetry might be suitable for a separate thread, though. Or it could be done in the same one that handles the clients that end up receiving the data. You don't give enough information to really say.